# C - strange sysmalloc assertion error after calling memset

Tags: c, memory

I'm relatively new to C programming and currently working on a simple Hashtable (I have experience in other languages tho).

But now I encountered a weird memory problem, and the pseudo solution I found is even weirder.
So, I have the following code, that sets up my Hashtable structure:

```
typedef struct HashTable {
    unsigned int size;
    TableEntry *table[];
} HashTable;

HashTable *create_table(unsigned int size) {
    HashTable *table = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) + size*sizeof(TableEntry *)); 
    memset(table + sizeof(unsigned int), 0, size*sizeof(TableEntry *));       
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}
```

I ran this code on two machines. On my windows host machine, this works completly fine.
But my linux VM  apperenly doesn't like me, because after the memset call, any malloc call will throw an assertion errror

```
server: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0) failed.
```

I already spend hours trying to find out what's causing the error here. I figure it probably has sth to do with the memset call, but that didn't help me so far. I also used Valgrind, but that didn't give me any new information either.

Now comes the part the part that confuses me the most. A second malloc between the malloc and the memset call somehow fixes the problem (example given below). Even if I'm allocating 0 bytes, it still works fine.

So my "fix" looks sth like this:

```
HashTable *create_table(unsigned int size) {
    HashTable *table = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int) + size*sizeof(TableEntry *)); 
    void *test = malloc(0); //this line
    memset(table + sizeof(unsigned int), 0, size*sizeof(TableEntry *));       
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}
```

Now, I'd be very very thankful if someone could help me find out

1. whats causing the error
2. why on earth does the second malloc call fix it? Probably just some weird C stuff, but I'm still curious

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when something magic "fixes" a problem, it is caused by undefined behavior earlier in your code.  Moving locations in the text or data segment may avoid the symptom you were seeing, but the underlying problem is still there.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned int)` should be `sizeof(HashTable)`, or `offsetof(HashTable, table)`. This allows for padding between the two members

Comment: using `calloc` instead of `malloc` would simplify the code and avoid the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Some programmer dude" pointed out the error, but there is a safer and more idiomatic way to write this.

Your approach is inherently not correct, because it assumes that the `table` array member of `HashTable` will start immediately following the `size` member.  But this is not necessarily true; the compiler may insert padding in between them.  Indeed, on 64-bit systems this will typically be the case, because `unsigned int` is likely to be 4 bytes, but pointers are expected to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary.  Your current code would also need to be updated every time you decide to add or remove members from `HashTable`.

So a better approach is as follows, taking advantage of the fact that `sizeof` applied to a `struct` type with a flexible array member will return the size of everything preceding the FAM, including any padding:

```
HashTable *create_table(unsigned int size) {
    HashTable *table = malloc(sizeof(HashTable) + size*sizeof(TableEntry *)); 
    memset(table->table, 0, size*sizeof(TableEntry *));       
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}
```

---

A couple other possible improvements:

- when using `sizeof`, many people prefer to "dereference" the pointer pointing to the desired object, rather than to name its type, as this is potentially less error prone.
- Sizes or lengths of arrays should generally use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`.  On a 64-bit system, your current code would be unable to handle hash tables larger than 4 GB, even though the system might support such large objects just fine.
- It's awkward to use the name `table` both for your local variable in `create_table` and for the member of `HashTable`.
- You should check that `malloc` succeeded before attempting to initialize the allocated memory.

I might write:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct HashTable {
    size_t size;
    TableEntry *entries[];
} HashTable;

HashTable *create_table(size_t size) {
    HashTable *table = malloc(sizeof(*table) + size*sizeof(table->entries[0]));
    if (!table) {
        // abort or return NULL
    }
    memset(table->entries, 0, size*sizeof(table->entries[0]));       
    table->size = size;
    return table;
}
```

Left as an exercise: properly handle the case in which the parameter `size` is so large that `sizeof(*table) + size*sizeof(table->entries[0])` overflows `size_t`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! To detect an overflow, could I just write sth like: `if((SIZE_MAX-sizeof(*table)) / sizeof(table->entries[0])) <= size)` ? Or would that approach be considered unelegant/wrong in C?

Comment: @mizanshu: Yes, that's a good way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that pointer arithmetic is done in the base unit of the pointer, this is what leads to e.g. `p[i]` is the exact same as `*(p + i)` (for any valid pointer or array `p` and index `i`).

That means your expression `table + sizeof(unsigned int)` will be the same as `&table[sizeof(unsigned int)]`, which is probably not what you expect. This in turn leads your `memset` call to write out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

To be correct you need to cast the pointer `table` to a pointer of `char`, as in `(char *) table + sizeof(unsigned int)`.

---

The difference between the two are the *byte* offsets added.

With plain `table + sizeof(unsigned int)` (without the casting) then you add `sizeof(HashTable) * sizeof(unsigned int)` *bytes* to the pointer.

When you cast the pointer, as in `(char *) table + sizeof(unsigned int)` you are adding `sizeof(char) * sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes to the pointer.

Comment: You've identified the problem, but as I note in my answer, I don't think your fix is really the right one.